# system.timer.timer doesn't starts

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have my timer

```
System.Timers.Timer progress = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
progress.SynchronizingObject = this;
progress.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
progress.AutoReset = false;
```

it is disabled, then in some function I try to:

```
if(!flag)
    progress.enabled = true;   //it doesn't change to true.??
```

Why?

Comment: timer.enabled = false; without change

Comment: You set it to fire once. Are you sure it _never_ elapses, like before you are expecting it?

Comment: What do you want to do ? What the phase ? :-/

Comment: have you tried progress.start(); ? the .enabled is more a check to see if timer is running, not to get it running

Comment: How about if it has already elapsed? Cant I start it once more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading through [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx#Y456) a bit i found this line:

If the Timer is already enabled when the Start method is called, the interval is reset. If AutoReset is false, the Start method must be called in order to start the count again.

this tells me that you can manually restart your timer with timer.start();

when looking further i found an example which stated you need to protect your timer for garbage collection:

```
    // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use
    // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring
    // before the method ends.
    //GC.KeepAlive(yourTimer);
```

i hope you can work further on this

Comment: I check whether it was already disposed but it is alive, even though it doesn't change. timer.enabled == timer.start();  I have no idea how is it possible:/

Answer (score 0):

You can start the timer with

```
progress.Start();
```

whitch sets Enabled to true (see documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer.start.aspx)

```
Enabled
```

steht in der MSDN wie folgt: "Ruft einen Wert ab, der angibt, ob Timer das Elapsed-Ereignis auslösen soll, oder legt diesen fest."

bezieht sich folglich nur auf das Elapsed Ereignis und nicht auf das Starten bzw. Stoppen den Timers an sich.

Answer (score -1):

I have one timer in my software and I did like this :

```
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0); 

        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        myDispatcherTimer.Interval = ts; 
        myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
        myDispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {
        //Your Method here
    }
```